# How to get information from my controller to my form?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

For a form I'm trying to add a selectbox which contains a list of items from my database.

My form is situated in /application/forms/News/Edit.php

In my controller I want to fetch this list which I want to use in my form.

How can I add that list from my controller to my form?

This is how my code in Edit.php looks like:

```
$this->addElement(
   'select',
    'view_status',
    array(
       'label' => 'View status',
       'multioptions' => array(
          //THIS SHOULD BE FILLED WITH DYNAMIC CONTENT FROM MY CONTROLLER
       )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the options of your select in the first param of the form constructor. When initialising the form, Zend_Form look for a set method postfixed by the option name:

```
class App_Form_News_Edit extends Zend_Form
{
    public function setViewStatusOptions($options)
    {
        $this->view_status->setMultioptions($options);
    }
}

$form = new App_Form_News_Edit(array('viewStatusOptions' => array(..)));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller's action, you could initialize the options you wants depending on the action. You should set the optoions before sending the form to the view.

```
$Form = new form_News_Edit();
$Form->getElement('view_status')
   ->setMultioptions($arrayOptions);

$this->view->assign('Form', $Form);
```

Comment: Edited your question by accident sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the constructor or _init function of your forms class to set any custom values you would have. 
It would get you something looking like (in your controller):

```
$myForm = new form_News_Edit($myArrayOfValues);
```

Then in your forms class :

```
public function __construct($myArrayOfValue){
```

....

```
$this->addElement(
   'select',
    'view_status',
    array(
       'label' => 'View status',
       'multioptions' => $myArrayOfValue
    )
);
```

}

yvoyer's Solution is good too but takes out some of the business logic for the form out of it.